# Как сделать Push уведомления на ReactNative Expo

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

как сделать Push уведомления на ReactNative Expo при этом не использовав сервис Expo Notifications и не лезть в код xCode или Android studio?

Comment: а что в документации к ReactNative пишут на этот счет?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios#__docusaurus

Comment: Пишут что нужно через xcode импортировать разрешения, хотелось бы все реализовать только на JS

Comment: мое предложение, если не хотите потому создавать еще один вопрос: "а как пофиксить ..., если все написал на js" - делать как в доке